# Created one MVC solution called "MvcWebRole". In this area I created a folder named "Content" to store my css files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress

I want to access "Css" files from my application folder structure. 
    I have given like this

```
<pre>
<code>
 <link rel='stylesheet' id='spoton-style-css' href="~MvcWebRole/Content/wp-content/plugins/cloudidx-layout-option/assets/css/spoton-stylea560.css?ver=3.9.1" type='text/css' media='all'
```

But "Css" reference was not taking from project folder.

Can any one can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='spoton-style-css' href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wp-content/plugins/cloudidx-layout-option/assets/css/spoton-stylea560.css")" type='text/css' media='all' />
```